# How do I split multiple strings in an array with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var myArray = [ "name1+data1" , "name2+data2" , "name3+data3", "name4+data4" ]
```

When the user enters `name1`, I would like to open an alert box and display `data1`, for `name2` it should display `data2`, and so on.

In order to do this, I was wondering how I could split all the strings without using more than one array? And how do I display only `data1` when `name1` is entered by the user?
I’ve tried using `myArray.split("+")` but it does not work.

Comment: Probably want to use an associative map (e.g., a JS object) for something like this. `.split()` turns a single string into an array split by the given delimiter; it doesn't apply to arrays as you are using it here.

Comment: `myArray` is already an array, split will not work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got the downvotes. It's a pretty basic javascript question, but it's perfectly coherent and well stated. Proper capitalization is expected on Stack Overflow. Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You could map the splitted strings and get an object form the key/value pairs.

```js
var array = ['name1+data1', 'name2+data2', 'name3+data3', 'name4+data4'],
    object = Object.fromEntries(array.map(s => s.split('+')));
    
console.log(object);
```

Comment: Cool. `fromEntries` is a new one to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing below function that takes two arguments.
targetArray is the array to perform search and searchString is the string to search. In your case searchString would be `name1`. The time complexity is based on the position of the element in the array O(K).

```
function findMatch(targetArray, searchString) {
  const targetElement = targetArray.find(item => {
    const leftSplit = item.split('+')[0];
    return leftSplit === searchString;
  });
  if (targetElement) {
    return targetElement.split('+')[1];
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

```
  window.alert(
    findMatch([ "name1+data1" , "name2+data2" , "name3+data3", "name4+data4" ], 'name2')
  );
Alerts: "data2"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an array, then you need to iterate through the array.

```
const output = myArray.filter(arrayItem => arrayItem.includes(userInput))[0].split('+')[0];
```

The time complexity here would be O(N+M), where N is length of array and M is the length of the string.

I think it would be better if `myArray` is maintained as a dictionary,

```
const myArray = {
    name1: 'data1',
    name2: 'data2',
    name3: 'data3'
}
const output = myArray[userInput];
```

The time complexity would be decreased to O(1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this snippet

```
var myArray = [ "name1+data1" , "name2+data2" , "name3+data3", "name4+data4" ];
var userValue = prompt('Valeur à rechercher...');
myArray.map((item) => { 
    if(~item.search(userValue) && userValue.length > 0){
        alert(item.split('+')[1]);
        return false;
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here's an example where name1 and name2 have values, but not the others:

```
let pairs = [ "name1+data1" , "name2+data2" , "name3+", "name4+" ]
```

We can split each of those into two-element arrays:

```
let arr = pairs.map(p=>p.split('+'))
```

And filter out the ones with empty names:

```
arr = arr.filter(a=>a[1].length > 0)

arr.join("\n")  // "name1,data1
                //  name2,data2"
```

Does that do what you want?

Comment: I’ve tried this code and I’ve found that when I type in "name1", the outputs are "data2", "data3", "data4" instead of just "data1". Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry. That'll teach me to post answers without checking that they work! I fixed it, and hopefully made it clearer as well.